# CSS defined edges with blur transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-filters

I am making a large button with a blurred background image that unblurs when you hover over it. I have used a container with overflow hidden and made the margin negative on the background image so that the edges are defined.

However, when I hover over the image and it does the transition from blurred to unblurred, or vice versa, the edges of the image are no longer defined. This creates an effect where the edges of the white container underneath it will be visible. While completely blurred or completely unblurred, these edges immediately become defined again.

How can I fix this?

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 2.5vh;
    left: 2.5vh;
    width: 50vh;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
    background-image: url(https://www.decorativefair.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/yellow-wallpaper-12-1024x640.jpg);
    margin: -5%;
    width: 110%;
    height: 110%;
    filter: blur(6px);
    transition: 1s;
}

.image:hover {
    filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="image"></div>
            placeholder text
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi and welcome to SO. Please isnert a minimal reproduciable code snippet (ctrl + m).

Comment: @tacoshy my bad, it's my first time posting here, it's in

Comment: unfortunatly I can not reproduce the error with the code provided. Is there any other code that is conflicting? have you cleared the browser cache already?

Comment: @tacoshy I've cleared my browser cache and I can see the issue when I run the code snippet here

Comment: intresting. can you provide a screenshot of it? like I said, I really have no white background if I hover. What browser are you using?

Comment: It shows up at the edges of the image while it's blurring in and out. I'm using chrome

Comment: @tacoshy [here](https://imgur.com/a/xbODIHh)'s a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a browser bug.

the container background can be seen at the borders.

It can be made less visible if the container background is the same than the image. I have used inherit in the image to avoid setting it in 2 places.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 2.5vh;
    left: 2.5vh;
    width: 50vh;
    height: 50vh;
    background-image: url(https://www.decorativefair.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/yellow-wallpaper-12-1024x640.jpg);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
    background-image: inherit;
    margin: -5%;
    width: 110%;
    height: 110%;
    filter: blur(6px);
    transition: 1s;
}

.image:hover {
    filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="image"></div>
            placeholder text
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works to an extent, but in my current code the button is big enough where the defined edges still stand out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be caused by the negative margin and 110% width and height settings in the `.image` css class. I assume you're doing that to try and maintain a crisp edge when blurred. I modified those and the snippet below shows the result. Hopefully it will be useful:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 2.5vh;
    left: 2.5vh;
    width: 50vh;
    height: 50vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
    background-image: url(https://www.decorativefair.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/yellow-wallpaper-12-1024x640.jpg);
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    filter: blur(6px);
    transition: 1s;
}

.image:hover {
    filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="image"></div>
            placeholder text
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This makes it consistent, but still not the effect I want. I'll experiment putting a background image behind it so the edges aren't noticable.